# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>

Tags: react-native, react-redux

**Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React**

*

### I think the issue is with the new react context api...

Check 'Wei Gao' post on the same

https://dev.to/wgao19/upgrading-to-react-redux-v6-around-the-new-context-api-5725

*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import{connect, Provider} from 'react-redux';

import store  from './Redux/store.js';

const ContextA = React.createContext();
class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Provider store = {store} context = {ContextA} > 
        <View >
          <Text> Contacts </Text>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
const mapStP= state =>({contacts : state.contacts});
export default connect(mapStP, null , null, {context : ContextA})(App);
```

## Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen the provider's context as 'ContextA' rather than an app. So there is no definition of context in the app. It's hard to figure out exactly what you want, but you can solve this problem like this.

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
        <View >
          <Text> Contacts </Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Your component

**Yourcomponent.js**

```js
const ContextA = React.createContext();
const mapStP= state =>({contacts : state.contacts});
...
return (
    <Provider store={store} context={ContextA}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
);
...
compose(
  connect(mapStP, null, null, { context: ContextA }),
)(Yourcomponent);
```

Comment: still unable to figure out :( 
Here's snack for the same https://snack.expo.io/@cu.17bcs/issue01